# Django: ValidationError ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Django: ValidationError ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'] i have been getting this error when i use the forminline factory module, im sorry if my question isnt placed properly, this is my first time here.

my form template is this:

```
{% extends 'accounts/main-form.html'%}
{% load static %}


{% block title %}
    <title>CRM | Form</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block link %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style1.css'%}">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {{formset.management_form}}
        {% for i in formset %}
            {{i}}
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="submit">
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock%}
```

this is the form code in views.py

```
def order_form(request, pk):
    customers = Customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    OrderFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Customer, Order, fields=('product', 'status',))
    formset = OrderFormSet(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = OrderFormSet(request.POST, instance=customers)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return redirect('/')
    context = {'formset': formset}
    return render(request, 'accounts/order_form.html', context)
```

my models

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Indoor', 'Indoor'),
        ('OutDoor', 'Outdoor')
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CATEGORY)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered')
    )
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete= models.DO_NOTHING)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=STATUS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

my form.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Order


class Order_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['product', 'status']
```

Comment: @sansui o- I am a bit confused. Let me ask.     formset = OrderFormSet(request.POST)
This formset contains POST data. What happenns in the context of a GET request? Shouldn't it be     formset = OrderFormSet() in the GET request and     formset = OrderFormSet(request.POST) inside the POST block?

Comment: Thanks for the observation, im passing a request data before checking if the method is POST, i removed the request.post and passed the instance and it worked fine